# In openstreemap/leaflet how to display in real time the coordinates in a small tooltip when the mouse moves over the map

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, openstreetmap

I want that when i move the mouse over the map it will display like in a small tool tip balloon the coordinates in real time on the mouse cursor for example like:  35.56, 56.765

I tried this code in my wix site but it's showing the map but the coordinate with the mouse is not working showing anything.

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
   <style>
      body, html, #map {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="map"></div>

   <script>
      var map = L.map('map').setView([32.921, 39.562], 10);
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
         attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
      }).addTo(map);

      var marker = L.marker([32.921, 39.562]).addTo(map);
      marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello World!</b><br>This is a customizable popup.").openPopup();

      // Create a tooltip to show coordinates
      var tooltip = L.tooltip({
         permanent: true,
         direction: 'bottom',
         opacity: 0.7
      });

      // Add the tooltip to the map
      tooltip.addTo(map);

      // Event listener for mousemove
      map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
         var latlng = e.latlng;
         tooltip.setLatLng(latlng).setContent('Coordinates: ' + latlng.lat.toFixed(6) + ', ' + latlng.lng.toFixed(6));
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the console, there is an error on your tooltip creation. You need to give it a latlng value when you create it, then it works (it moves around with the mouse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a small issue with how you are creating the tooltip. Instead of L.tooltip, you should use L.marker to create a marker for displaying the tooltip

```html
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
   <style>
      body, html, #map {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="map"></div>

   <script>
      var map = L.map('map').setView([32.921, 39.562], 10);
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
         attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
      }).addTo(map);

      var marker = L.marker([32.921, 39.562]).addTo(map);
      marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello World!</b><br>This is a customizable popup.").openPopup();

      // Create a marker for displaying the tooltip
      var tooltipMarker = L.marker([0, 0], { opacity: 0 }).addTo(map);

      // Event listener for mousemove
      map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
         var latlng = e.latlng;
         tooltipMarker.setLatLng(latlng);
         tooltipMarker.bindTooltip('Coordinates: ' + latlng.lat.toFixed(6) + ', ' + latlng.lng.toFixed(6), {
            permanent: true,
            direction: 'bottom'
         }).openTooltip();
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, I've created a hidden marker `tooltipMarker` that is used to display the tooltip. It listens to the `mousemove` event and updates its position and content accordingly.

screenshot

[image]

Comment: the marker the left coordinate is just under the mouse cursor so it's a bit hiding the coordinate the left coordinate.  is there a way to change the marker of the coordinates position so it will be a bit above or bottom the mouse cursor ?  in your screenshot it seems the black marker/cursor is a bit under the left coordinate in my side it's just over it.

Comment: Change `direction` to the `top`